# Android App Widget advanced(?) layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm new to android programming.  I would like to make an app widget that will display a set of contact images and allow me to call or send a text message of the person whose picture I press.

If you notice the bottom widget in the image, there are two oversized pictures (top left and bottom right) that seem as if they could not fit into a linearlayout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H13i7.jpg

How is this done, what I'm asking is which app widget layout would I use to align images as they are in the bottom widget on this screen?

Edit: I'm new, but I have plenty of time to learn this, so I figure I'll press forward.  I get the feeling I would be able to take images and combine them into a single master image with a whole lot of flexibility.

http://androidattop.blogspot.com/2012/06/merge-multiple-images-into-one-image-in.html

Then I'd just have to figure out where on the image a user clicked. Or I could split only big images and use nested linearlayouts, which would save the custom click listener which looks like its more likely the way to go, but I worry about gaps in the larger images.

All advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this done

You would have to ask the authors of that app to determine how they did it.

> what I'm asking is which app widget layout would I use to align images as they are in the bottom widget on this screen?

That could most easily be accomplished with a `GridLayout` I think, but that is only available on API Level 16+ for app widgets.

Beyond that, use nested `LinearLayouts`. For example, a horizontal `LinearLayout` holding onto three vertical `LinearLayouts` would provide the basic skeleton. Each of those three vertical `LinearLayouts` would hold a subset of your imagery. For example, the middle `LinearLayout` would be a column of the three images.

That being said, if you are "new to android programming", I would recommend starting with a simpler project.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare So this would require breaking the multi-row images in half, or is it possible for an image to extend beyond the boundaries of its container in a linearlayout? I wonder if it could be done as an image-map, where the image is presented and the location of a click is captured to determine which "sub-image" was clicked and respond accordingly.

Comment: @user1561581: "So this would require breaking the multi-row images in half" -- no. Think of your overall layout as being five cells wide by three cells high (note: not "cells" in an app widget sense). You have two 2x2 cell images and a bunch of 1x1 cell images. The left- and right-hand `LinearLayouts` would be 2x3 cells, holding a 2x2 image and a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 2 1x1 images. The middle `LinearLayout` would hold 3 1x1 images. "I wonder if it could be done as an image-map" -- not in an app widget, sorry. You don't get pixel-level click info.